# Send inbox SMS to server via API

Tags: android, android-sms

I'm Developing an android application. I want to save inbox sms to sql database server. Here is my android code

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        try {
            if (bundle != null) {
                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                    DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar.setTimeInMillis(currentMessage.getTimestampMillis());
                    String cDate = df1.format(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE));
                    String cTime = df2.format(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
                    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                    String ime = tm.getDeviceId();
                    useGet(ime, cDate, cTime, "0", senderNum, message);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);
        }
    }
```

by `useGet(ime, cDate, cTime, "0", senderNum, message);` method I hit a url and want to save all hitted sms in my sql db.

Comment: If you hit a url then you can save on that page pageload event.

Comment: It appears that are looking to save SMS on your server. For that you'd need an API which takes bulk SMS (because hitting API per SMS will cost you extra bandwidth and slow down the process).

Comment: you have to buy sms gateway for sending massage its easy one line code gatway providor will provide

Comment: I want simply save sms in sql databse table from android studio. I do want to send sms anywhare.

Comment: Android has SQLite Database. For SQL, you'd have to go on Linux or Windows.